# Can't equalize anchor heights using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Seems like my JavaScript is not listening to me. I simply want to set all anchors' height to be equal to the highest height of these anchors.

#### HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 product-items" ng-repeat="products in products">
    <div class="product">
        <h3>{{products.title}}</h3>
        <img ng-href="" ng-src="{{products.thumbimg}}" alt="{{products.imgalt}}">
        <a href="#">{{products.link}}</a>
        <p>{{products.price | currency : ""}} BGN</p>
        <p>Free Shiping</p>
        <button>BUY</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("app", []);
    var MainController = function ($scope, $http, $filter) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        /* Jquery */
        var maxHeight = 0;
        $("div .product a").each(function () {
            if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
        });

        $("div .product a").height(maxHeight);


    };
    app.controller("MainController", MainController);
} ());
```

What about setting equal height on h1,h2 or h3 html elements

Comment: If your anchors are inline (default), their height setting is ignored. You can make them `display: inline-block` or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a>` elements are inline elements, and you can't change the height of an inline element using `height` in CSS. You have to change them to inline-block elements by adding this CSS code to your page:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```